# C++/CLI use a std::shared_ptr inside method of managed class

Tags: c++, c++-cli, smart-pointers

I have a managed class

```
private ref class Test
{
  public:
  std::shared_ptr<IData> DoSomething();
}
```

The method DoSomething() shell do the following

```
std::shared_ptr<IData> DoSomething()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Data> returnData = std::make_shared<Data>();
  // DoSomething
  return returnData;
}
```

`Data` => `IData`

This won't work, since the compiler tells me, that I am not allowed to use native code inside a managed class. How can I achieve what I need? `IData`/`Data`have to be native.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `returnData`, is not it of type `std::shared_ptr<Data>` and you are trying to return `IData`

Comment: @macroland not sure what you mean. Do you mean I should have done `IData returnData = std::make_shared<Data>();` ? Would not change my problem that I cannot use std::shared_ptr/std::make_shared

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Data>` and `IData` are not the same types, although `Data` might be derived from `IData`

Comment: Oh.. how can I fix that? Sorry I am new to C++

Comment: @HansPassant but Data is a native class. If I use instead `gcnew` it says gcnew may only be used to create an object with managed type

Comment: I think you'd need to store a pointer to a heap-allocated shared_ptr, and delete it in the finalizer